# Does the order of operations change within an if expression?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I recently came across something that I thought I understood right off the bat, but thinking more on it I would like understanding on why it works the way it does.

Consider the code below. The `(x-- == 9)` is clearly getting evaluated, while the `(y++ == 11)` is not. My first thought was that logical `&&` kicks in, sees that the expression has already become false, and kicks out before evaluating the second part of the expression.

The more I think about it, the more I don't understand why this behaves as it does. As I understand it, logical operators fall below increment operations in the order of precedence. Shouldn't `(y++ == 11)` be evaluated, even though the overall expression has already become false?

In other words, shouldn't the order of operations dictate that `(y++ == 11)` be evaluated before the `if` statement realizes the expression as a whole will be false?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;

    if( (x-- == 9) && (y++ == 11) )
    {
        cout << "I better not get here!" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Final X: " << x << endl;
    cout << "Final Y: " << y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Final X: 9
Final Y: 10
```

Comment: I've removed the [tag:C] tag as this is C++ code.

Comment: The principle applies as much to C as it does to C++, though. It's just the printing code (and that's beside the point) that differs.

Comment: +1. While the answer is trivial (short-circuit evaluation), this *does* point out a very tricky bug that can happen when you try to put too much on one line. Nice question.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> logical operators fall below increment operations in the order of
>   precedence.

Order of precedence is *not* order of execution. They're completely different concepts. Order of precedence only affects order of execution to the extent that operands are evaluated before their operator, and order of precedence helps tell you what the operands are of each operator.

Short-circuiting operators are a partial exception even to the rule that operands are evaluated before the operator, since they evaluate the LHS, then the operator has its say whether or not to evaluate the RHS, *maybe* the RHS is evaluated, then the result of the operator is computed.

Do not think of higher-precedence operations "executing first". Think of them "binding tighter". `++` has higher precedence than `&&`, and in the expression `x ++ && y ++`, operator precedence means that the `++` "binds more tightly" to `y` than `&&` does, and so the expression overall is equivalent to `(x++) && (y++)`, not `(x++ && y) ++`.

Comment: I certainly did *not* understand that distinction, thank you!

Answer (score 45):

> Shouldn't `(y++ == 11)` be evaluated, even though the overall expression has already become `false`?

No:  the `&&` and `||` operators short-circuit:  they are evaluated left-to-right and as soon as the result of the expression is known, evaluation stops (that is, as soon as the expression is known to be `false` in the case of a series of `&&`, or `true` in the case of a series of `||`)<sup>(*)</sup>.

There is no sense in doing extra work that doesn't need to be done.  This short-circuiting behavior is also quite useful and enables the writing of terser code.  For example, given a pointer to a struct-type object, you can test whether the pointer is null and then dereference the pointer in a subsequent subexpression, for example:  `if (p && p->is_set) { /* ... */ }`.

---

(*) Note that in C++, you can overload both the `&&` and the `||` for class-type operands and if you do, they lose their short-circuiting property (it is generally inadvisable to overload `&&` and `||` for this reason).

Comment: Also this behavior doesn't depend on being in an `if` statement.

Comment: @Peter: SO has almost 500k users. By the pigeonhole principle, at least 98% of users must be illiterate. ;-)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: I understand that it was meant to be a joke, but... how does using the pigeonhole principle lead to the conclusion that "98% of users must be illiterate", even using the most skewed logic?

Comment: @Ivan: It's a sarcastic comment about the fact that there's only a finite number of literate people (notionally set at 10,000 in my comment, or 2% of 500,000); that leaves 98% illiterate, the quota having long been used up.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: Isn't that the Law of Large Numbers rather than the Pigeonhole Principle?

Comment: @caf: Sort of but not quite, unless you're trying to say that the larger the population, the nearer the proportion of literate people approaches zero. :-)

Comment: @caf: (BTW, are you caf on #stackoverflow? If so, small world. :-P)

Comment: @James McNellis, sorry it wasn't supposed to come across that way. Your answer was valuable, and I did not down-vote you. I was just a little surprised that soo many people had *missed* the point. Two excellent answers were not getting the proper recognition.

Comment: @Peter:  My apologies then for misinterpreting your comment.

Answer (score 13):

Precedence and associativity do *not* specify the order in which the operations are actually performed.  They specify how operations are grouped: that is, in the following expression:

```
x && y++
```

...the lower precedence of `&&` says that it is grouped as if it was:

```
x && (y++)
```

rather than as

```
(x && y)++
```

In your expression, the relative precedence of `&&` and `++` do not matter, because you have separated those operators with parentheses anyway.

Grouping (and therefore precedence and associativity) specify *what* value each operator is operating on; but it specifies nothing about *when* it does so.

For most operators, the order in which the operations are performed is unspecified - however, in the case of `&&` it is specified to evaluate the left hand operand first, then only evaluate the right hand operand if the result of the left hand operand was non-zero.

Comment: I think this response actually answers what @dolphy was really asking. However, you say that for most operators the order is unspecified, are you sure this is true? I'm looking at the operators table and there is associatively defined for everything -- most happen to be from left to right.

Comment: @Peter: Associativity is still about which way the syntax binds---it doesn't determine execution order (see Steve Jessop's point).

Answer (score 7):

No. Order of precedence simply decides whether you get this:

```
A && B
```

(with `A` being `x-- == 9` and `B` being `y++ == 11`) or

```
A == B == C
```

(with `A` being `x--`, `B` being `9 && y++`, and `C` being 11).

Obviously, we're dealing with the first case. Short circuiting fully applies; if `A` is true, then `B` is not evaluated.

Comment: You also get a +1 for *actually* answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operators evaluate left-to-right and stop as soon as the result is known (an AND with a falsity or an OR with a true value).

Answer (score -2):

C standard does not dictate any particular order of expression evaluation in if. So behavior will be compiler specific and using this style of coding not portable. You face that problem because incrementing/decrementing of value is post operation, but standard says as post operation of expression where variable is used. So if a compiler considers that your expression is just single variable usage as x or y, then you will see one result. If a compiler thinks that expression is entire if expression evaluation, then you will see other result. I hope it helps.

Comment: Expressions are evaluated left to right, and only until the point where expression is known to be either true or false -- hence not the entire expression may be evaluated -- there is nothing here which is compiler dependent.

Comment: @Soren: Expressions _in general_ have no set order of evaluation. _However_, `&&` and `||` set a sequence point between the left- and right-hand sides, so that the left-hand side of `&&` and `||` are executed before the right-hand side (if at all). No other operator, other than `,`, works that way.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: The `?:` operator also introduces a sequence point after the first expression is evaluated.

Comment: No one seems bothered to look in assembler code generated by compiler, optimization rules allow to change order evaluation. When you raise certain point, please refer some source beside of your head.

Comment: @Dimitriy R: §6.5.13 of the C standard defines the `&&` operator.  Paragraph 4 of it says: *Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.* (sequence points are described in §5.1.2.3, as points in the execution where all previous side effects have taken place).