# How the given C code be interpretated by different Compiler

Tags: c

I have a code below and wanted to know what could be output.What i would like to see how different compiler would interpret this particular piece of code.

```
int main()
{
int i = -1, j = 2, k = 0, m;
m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
printf("\n %d %d %d %d \n", i, j, k, m);
return 0;
}
```

Now the question is while handling this code would compiler go by the rule which says

> This expresion can be seen as
>
> ```
>  m = ++i || (++j && ++k);
> ```
>
> as && has higher precedence over || and the result would     be 0 2 0 1

or

> This expresion can be seen as
>
> ```
> m = ++i || (++j && ++k);
> ```
>
> but compiler still will try to short circuit. so it evaluates ++i, since it's 1,(++j&&++k) >are not evaluated.so ans is 0 3 1 1

Comment: You can either read the spec and find out (better), or run the code and find out (faster). What is the purpose of asking this question here?

Comment: I wanted to know about this circuit rule..

Comment: @Jon did you read this post or just by seeing it you made it close??

Comment: You have the same (wrong) result in both cases!

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108467/is-short-circuit-evaluation-guaranteed-in-c-as-it-is-in-java

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783105/does-the-order-of-operations-change-within-an-if-expression/6783458#6783458, answer is the same. Short circuit means that it short circuits. It doesn't mean that it doesn't short-circuit. Hence, of your two options the correct one is the one that short-circuits, not the one that doesn't. Not sure about what you claim it prints, though. Anyway `++i` is 0, so short-circuiting has no effect in this example.

Comment: I Run this code on different compiler and on different compilers am getting different Output ,why so??

Comment: "so it evaluates ++i, since it's 1,..." but you initialized `i = -1`, so `++i` should evaluate to 0...

Comment: @Amit: either you aren't running this code, or you aren't reporting what it really output. There is no way that `i` starts at -1 and ends up -2. [Edit: oh, hang on, you forgot to include `<stdio.h>`, so the program has undefined behavior. That could explain incorrect output, and also why it differs on different implementations.]

Comment: I wonder why are there a rash of questions about short circuiting lately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `++i || ++j && ++k` will group like so due to precedence:

```
++i || (++j && ++k)
```

One of the few rules C has about evaluation order of expressions is that the left-hand side of the `||` and the `&& operators must execute before the right-hand side (for short circuiting).  This is a non-optional language requirement.

That means that `++i` has to be evaluated first.  It will return `0` (it does not evaluate to `1` as you mistakenly mention in the question).  Since that's not enough to short circuit the `||` operation, the right side will need to be evaluated.  A similar process will occur for evaluation the `&&` operator (and both sides of the `&&` operation will need to be evaluated).

The resulting output will be:

```
0 3 1 1
```

regardless of the compiler.  There is no undefined, unspecified, or implementation defined behavior evaluating that expression.

The expression `++i || ++j && ++k` will group like so due to precedence:

```
++i || (++j && ++k)
```

One of the few rules C has about evaluation order of expressions is that the left-hand side of the `||` and the `&& operators must execute before the right-hand side (for short circuiting).  This is a non-optional language requirement.

That means that `++i` has to be evaluated first.  It will return `0`.  Since that's not enough to short circuit the `||` operation, the right side will need to be evaluated.  A similar process will occur for evaluation the `&&` operator (and both sides of the `&&` operation will need to be evaluated).

The resulting output will be:

```
0 3 1 1
```

regardless of the compiler.  There is no undefined, unspecified, or implementation defined behavior evaluating that expression.

---

One way to get the output you mention in your question is to use the following expression instead:

```
m = --i || ++j && ++k;
```

In this case, `--i` evaluates to `-2` and the short circuiting rule requires that the right side of the `||` operator *not* be evaluated.  So `j` and `k` are left alone.